# Setting the ContentTypeId of a list item throws a SoapException

Tags: web-services, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Doing the following:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement updates = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
            updates.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            updates.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "0");
            updates.SetAttribute("ViewName", "");

updates.InnerXml = "<Method ID=\"1\" Cmd=\"Update\">" +
                "<Field Name=\"ID\">" + listItemId + "</Field>" +
                "<Field Name=\"Title\">ModifiedFile</Field>" +
                "<Field Name=\"FileRef\">" + theFileInSharepoint + "</Field>"+
                "<Field Type=\"ContentTypeId\">" + contentTypeId + "</Field></Method>";

myListSoapClient.UpdateListItems(myListGuid, updates);
```

The UpdatelistItems will throw (Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.) if the updates includes the `<Field Type=\"ContentTypeId\">` node.  Remove that, and the updates get applied.

Is modifying a listItem ContentTypeId possible through the web services for sharepoint?

Comment: Are you trying to update an item's content type id? Something that i've made is update an item's content type, as follows: "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field><Field Name='ContentType'>SubFolder</Field><Field Name='BaseName'>MyFolder</Field> <Field Name='ID'>New</Field></Method>". Not sure about what are you trying to do.

Comment: Yep.  Trying to update a list item's contenttype.

Comment: Thanks.  Something similar to that worked: <Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='ID'>" + listItemId + "</Field><Field Name=\"Title\">ModifiedFile</Field><Field Name='FSObjType'>0</Field><Field Name='ContentType'>" + contentTypeName + "</Field></Method>" Though, I'm still wondering why directly modifying the contenttypeid isn't working.  It looks like it should be possible from the WebServiceList schema docs, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437580(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Nice to hear that! Well, i think that is not possible cause the ContentTypeId is (maybe) a read-only field. Not sure, but is not an "item property", but a "content type property", So you would have to modify the content type, no the item. Not really sure of that. I mean, ContentType and ContentTypeID props are not the same.  best regards!